# How can I remove all the duplicate rows including the original one in SQL?

Tags: mysql, sql, phpmyadmin

I have a table like this:

```
id   id2
1    435  
2    345
3    345
4    567
5    456
6    987
7    987
```

Here in `id2` `345` and `987` are repeating twice, so I want to delete both the rows. My new table should look like this:

```
id   id2
1    435  
4    567
5    456
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can remove them from a `select` just by using aggregation:

```
select min(id), id2
from t
group by id2
having count(*) = 1;
```

If you want to remove them from the table, use `join` and `group by`:

```
delete t
    from t join
         (select id2, count(*) as cnt
          from t
          group by id2
         ) tt
         on t.id2 = tt.id2
    where cnt > 1;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `not exists` :

```
select *
from table t
where not exists (select 1 from table t1 where t1.id2 = t.id2 and t1.id <> t.id);
```

Same you can remove the records :

```
delete t
from table t 
where exists (select 1 from table t1 where t1.id2 = t.id2 and t1.id <> t.id);
```